# CSS: Width and Max-Width

Tags: css

Why does:

```
width: 98%;
max-width: 1140px;
```

do the same as

```
width: 1140px;
max-width: 98%;
```

The first one makes sense in that I'm saying the width is 98% but don't go larger than 1140px wide.

The second one however would say the page is 1140px wide but then WOULD go as large as the page at 98% right? So e.g past 1140px... but apparently not, as it does the same as the first.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: this will give you the complete knowledge about  the width and max-width :  https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/css-question-what-is-the-difference-between-width-and-maxwidth

Answer (score 27):

From my understanding of the properties:

```
if width > max-width use max-width
if max-width > width use width
```

Therefore, using your example, this must mean that 1140px is strictly less than 98% at the screen resolution you are viewing at.

Shrink your browser screen and you will get different results.

It's somewhat unrelated, but I've found `max-width` (and the corresponding property `max-height`) to be a problem with images in Internet Explorer, and found this to be helpful in coaxing it to use the correct values:

```css
img {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 120px;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Without the last two properties, most standard-compliant browsers correctly maintain aspect ratio, but Internet Explorer will not unless you do that.

**Edit:** It looks like I've said basically the same answer as everyone else.

Answer (score 7):

If you set a fixed `width` and a `max-width`, this means the following:

If the width goes above `max-width`, keep it at `max-width`.
If the width is below `max-width`, keep it on `width`.

It will never go over the `max-width`, that doesn't mean it can't stay under, the `max` keyword obviously indicates a limit and not a rule.

Answer (score 4):

In your first example

```
width: 98%;
max-width: 1140px;
```

you are telling the browser to give a width of 98% of the screen, but not bigger than 1140px.

In your second example,

```
width: 1140px;
max-width: 98%;
```

you are telling the browser to give a width of 1140px but not larger than 98% of the browser.

But, in the second instance, your screen size would need to be smaller than 1140px for the max-width value to kick in.

**Also note** that `max-width` is buggy in many older versions of IE.

Read more here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the container is your browser window, if you are on a 1280 px screen resolution then 98% would be 1254 px, which is still greater than 1140 px. So you see no difference. Try moving to lower resolution such as 1024px

Comment: Yeah but why wouldn't it expand PAST 1140px as the max-width is set to 98% so surely it would be 98% of the view and if the view is 1600px then it would go past 1140 right?

Comment: No, your `width` is set to 1140px and your `max-width` is set to 98%. That means it won't go OVER 98%, nobody said anything about UNDER 98%

Comment: but if I view on 1600px screen 98% would be bigger than 1140px so how come it doesn't stretch to that? width shouldn't stop it as I'm telling it the max width can be 98% and not a fixed size

Comment: Like I said, 98% might be bigger than `1140px`, but the `max-width` only indicates a limit. That means it will never stretch to `max-width`, only shrink.

Comment: it won't cause you set a fixed width to 1140px, as I said in the comment of my answer

Comment: AFAIK, it takes the smaller value if you view on 1600px screen where 98% is bigger than 1140px. As mentioned [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width)

Answer (score 1):

Probably in your first case 98% is equal or more than 1140px, so it will stick at 1140px.

In the second case of course, the width is 1140px, so it will stick to 1140px, and the max-width become useless.

**Update**
Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: the max-width isn't useless because it DOES keep the container 98% but never past 1140px in BOTH versions...

Comment: then you would simply do width:98%; having them both is sensless.

Answer (score 1):

The two options should essentially produce the *same* result, even with a width of less than `1140px`, e.g. `500px`:

In the first case:

```
width = min(98% * 500px, 1140px) = min(490px, 1140px) = 490px;
```

In the second case:

```
width = min(1140px, 98% * 500px) = min(1140px, 490px) = 490px;
```

However, there is a problem with certain browsers, in particular **firefox 12.0**, if you use the second option within a `fieldset` element. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nnu5G/). Drag the browser window and you will notice that the first `input` element which uses percentage `max-width` doesn't respond correctly.

As such, please use the first option:

```
width: percentage;
max-width: pixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

here is how I understand them .. 
they are 2 boxes -> width and max -width .

width can't exceed max-width if so width has no effect .
like wise if you defined max-width lower than width .. width has no effect .

at anytime your browser converts your % into most likely pixels
yet the rules above still apply .

examples :

```
width: 98%;
max-width: 1140px;
```

this is translated to :

```
width : 1960px;
max-width : 1140px;
```

this means -> only max width applies .

```
width: 1140px;
max-width: 98%;
```

this is translated to :

```
width : 1140;
max-width : 1960px;
```

this means -> width is 1140 but can't exceed 1960 .

Answer (score 0):

width - this css property used to set the width(fixed width), the width is fixed in this case.

Example: 
    .property-set{
       width: 200px;
    }

This set fixed width i.e 200px

max-width - this css property is used to set width but in this width may be less than what the value is set, but max limit is the value that set by user.

Example: 
    .property-set{
       max-width: 200px;
    }

This set max width i.e 200px which means width may be less than 200px but not more than 200px

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 98%;
max-width: 1140px;
```

This means width of the element should be 98% of its parent's width but not more than 1140px. so when the width of browser decreases the width of element shrinks and its width is always 98% but when the width of browser increases the width of element grows but not more than 1140px

```
width: 1140px;
max-width: 98%;
```

This means when the width of browser is less than 1140px the width of element shrinks and its width is always 98% of its parent but when the width of browser increases the width of element grows but not more than 1140px

Answer (score -1):

Use only

```
max-width: 1140px;
```

or

```
width: 98%;
```

not both.
If you want to see the difference go [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5PLUpt34MQ).

Comment: What value does your new answer add to the existing ones and does it really answer the question? I don't think so.