# Determine image aspect ratio is appropriate

Tags: javascript, php, aspect-ratio

Aloha,

how do I determine/calculate whether an image aspect ratio is appropriate (proportion) in Javascript programatically, based on these information?

For Example:
Below is ok:

```
Width = 570px
Height = 520px
Ratio = 10
Aspect = 57:52
```

This is not ok:

```
Width = 815px
Height = 85px
Ratio = 5
Aspect = 163:17
```

Comment: @pakito how is ratio being calculated?

Comment: What exactly do you need this for in javascript? If (on the offhand chance) you are trying to get images to maintain aspect ratio when resizing you might want to look at this (the last part of this post): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456468/css-width-and-max-width/6456638#6456638

Comment: @Ben I got it from here : http://blog.angrymango.com/?tag=/aspect-ratio

Comment: @Anthony: I am reading images from other website and want to display images which are proportion and at least meet the minimum width and height of 50px. Is like Facebook when you type in an URL, it will only choose those images with "good" ratio.

Comment: @pakito what specifically are you trying to accept or exclude? is it (height/width)<=ratio?

Comment: @Ben I have a minimum width 50px by height 50px restriction. Anything above for example 60by60, I will calculate its ratio. I want to allow only images with proportion size rather than some images with 200px by 60px or 815pxby50px

Comment: @pakito proportion size means what? A square?

Comment: @pakito i will assume you mean close to a square, please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Close to square or at least like something for me to set a restriction to determine whether the image is big enough for viewing? Have you tried Facebook? I believe they do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the aspect ratio to be within 20% of a square then do this:

```
maxOff=0.2; //percent margin of aspect ratio acceptance... (20%)
if ((width/height)>=(1-maxOff)&&(width/height)<=(1+maxOff)) {
//image is ok
}
```

Comment: @Ben Based on an image w67 by h52, I got 1.2884615..etc...kinda weird?

Comment: @Ben But ben, kinda close to something like that with a minimum or maximum percentage. I believe the code is something like what @SDuke provided below with reminder:

    ((Width/Height)%ratio==0)

But this doesn't work as well..

Comment: @pakito just adjust the percentage (maxOff).

Comment: @Ben really appreciate but still no dice. http://pastie.org/2135974
Is it because of the || ?

Comment: @pakito yes im sorry it is the ||. here is a good jsfiddle of it. http://jsfiddle.net/ben7005/gzpek/7/

Comment: @i fixed it in my answer... check out the jsfiddle, i think it's what you want

Comment: Wow! Guys we have a winner! Kudos to Ben! It works like a charm! Thanks a zillion Ben and everyone for the challenge, really appreciated big time! :D

Comment: Btw Ben, is the maxOff percentage just a tweak or is it possible to calculate? Like for example what will 0.4, 0.5, 0.6 percent tells me what kind of image size to expect?

Comment: @pakito 0.4 will give you a margin of error of 40%, meaning that the aspect ratio can be anywhere from a (simplified) 0.6:1 to 1.4:1. (The height and width can vary from each other by 40%).

Comment: @Ben Yes I accepted already :) Thanks for the explanation and everything Ben.

Comment: @pakito i made this jsfiddle (i think it's neater than the original example) http://jsfiddle.net/ben7005/uBSDD/

Comment: Definitely! Also I search around everywhere and can't seems to find this question around. Mostly about dynamically resizing proportionally with aspect ratio but not restricting it like how this is solved. People would find this useful in future definitely. Ben ftw! :)

Answer (score 2):

If that 'Ratio' value is the maximum allowable, then:

```
if (Ratio < (Width / Height)) {
    ... bad ratio ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'm still figuring out using your logic. But it seems like image with w245px × h63px is passed through. SHould I be setting a limit or something?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just divide Height with Width, and then pass the result to an if statement that accepts numbers bigger than X and smaller than Y? If the result of the divide calculation doesn't fit, the proportions are off.

Comment: hmm doesn't seems like logical? The images are uploaded by user, many height and width are dfferent and hard to determine using divide?

Comment: My answer was basicly the same as you accepted, without an example. Language barrier I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var nh=0;
var nw=0;
if (Width>Height) 
{
    nw=100;//or whatever you want the new thing to be.
    nh=(100*Height)/Width;
}
else
{
    nh=100;//same as before just switched
    nw=(100*Height)/Width;
}
```

then just set the size to nw,nh

Comment: This doesn't seems to work too? I based on an image of w67 by h52

Comment: @pakito, are you dividing by the ratio? If so, I think I might have put that backwards `if ratio%((Width/Height)==0)`

Comment: How should I refactor the code? Referring to this simple test, It seems like doesn't work. http://pastie.org/2135909