# How to align a div side by side within another div

Tags: html, css

I have a main div which has another two divs with in, I am trying to put the inner divs side by side. I have trie the following code, but I can't understand why it doesn't work. If apply float to my inner div they just disappear. Here is my code:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<div id="leftSide"></div>
<div id="rightSide"> </div>
</div>



 body{
        background-color: #006847;
    }

    #mainContainer{
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        max-width: 95%;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        box-shadow:10px 10px 5px red;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    #leftSide{
        background-color: #CE1126;
        max-width: 40%;
        height: 900px;
    }
    #rightSide{
        max-width: 50%;
        height: 900px;
        background-color: purple;
        float: right;
    }
```

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/ft5ef/) Check it out

Comment: Your main container wont hold its content with `height 900px;`

Comment: also use 'width:x' instead of 'max-width:x'. That's partially why your divs didn't display

Comment: @Alexander http://jsfiddle.net/vLa4r/?

Comment: @IndieRok what is the problem with max-width?

Comment: @Alexander you should use max-width to override the specified `width`. So plz specify `width`

Comment: @IndieRok you totally right, it works now.

Comment: Exactly, like Pilot said, a width needs to be specified in order for max-width to work

Comment: @IndieRok I understand now. In other words, it is better to work with width.

Comment: @Alexander updated the answer below, to give you a better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify width of container and then use max/min-width to override it,

Try,

```
body {
    background-color: green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#mainContainer {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 95%;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 5px grey;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#leftSide {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 40%;    
    height: 900px;
    float: left;
}

#rightSide {
    width: 60%;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `display:inline-block;`

Change the `height` of your inner divs to `500px` since your containers `height` is `500px`.

Change `max-width` to `width`. `width` needs to be specified in order for `max-width` to work.

> If you set a fixed width and a max-width, this means the following:
>
> If the width goes above max-width, keep it at max-width. If the width
>   is below max-width, keep it on width.

**[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6456625/3739658)**

**Change to this:**

```
#leftSide{
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#rightSide{
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mvLz3/)**

Comment: Thank you, it makes a lot of more sense now.

Comment: @Alexander why do you keep changing the accepted answer?

Comment: I accepted Pilots answer first, I wish I can give you credit as well because you answer works too. Sorry @imbondbaby

Answer (score 0):

Try not making the height of #mainContainer higher than the others:

```
#mainContainer{
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        max-width: 95%;
        **height: 900px;**
        margin: 0 auto;
        box-shadow:10px 10px 5px red;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
```

Comment: I don'n think the height has nothing to do with my problem. Thank you though

Comment: You sure? It fixed it for me.

Comment: I don't think so, you should check the other solutions from the other programmers :)

Answer (score -1):

I simplified your code and turned it into a JSFiddle. Basically, you don't want `floats` unless very necessary. Use `display:inline-block;` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/KybKc/