# CSS in Page overflows on mobile site

Tags: html, css

The site in question is:

http://www.thewaterqualitysolution.com/

the css code I'm using for the columns is:

```
.column1,
.column2,
.column3,
.column4
{
    column-rule-width: medium;
    width: 282px;
    max-width: 24%;

}

.column1,
.column2,
.column3
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 24px;
    max-width: 24%;
}

.column4
{
    float: right;
    max-width: 24%;
}
```

Why won't they stay in bounds?

Comment: Because your wrapper has 980px, so columns take 24% of that size... Please check css media queries for creating mobile views...

Comment: This question is not answerable because it lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the site you have declared a CSS rule for the columns twice. Your second declaration overwrites the first. Forcing all columns to a width of 282px. See default.css, line 510.

Also I recommend you read this post for a better understanding of CSS width and max-width.

[CSS: Width and Max-Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456468/css-width-and-max-width)