# Image scale based on browser size not working

Tags: html, css

would you know why the picture doesn't scale up/down on browser resize despite `max-width:100%` and `height:auto` ? Many thanks

See: http://jsfiddle.net/do5fzkhu/1/

```
#content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.atelier-beaute {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    z-index: 14;
    width: 58.5%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 90px;
    line-height: 1.38;
    text-align: justify;
    color: rgb(71, 64, 50);
}
.presentation img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 170px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.presentation-1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: You have a clearfix class in your demo HTML but not in your CSS so the float isn't being contained. See - http://jsfiddle.net/do5fzkhu/5/ Then your code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `width:100%;` instead of `max-width:100%;`

See: [CSS: Width and Max-Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456468/css-width-and-max-width)

Updated code below:

```css
#content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.atelier-beaute {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    z-index: 14;
    width: 58.5%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 90px;
    line-height: 1.38;
    text-align: justify;
    color: rgb(71, 64, 50);
}
.presentation img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 170px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.presentation-1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <section class="presentation presentation-1 clearfix">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/" />
        <article class="atelier-beaute wow fadeInRight">
            <h1>L'atelier <b>beauté</b></h1>
            
            <h2>Un moment, un instant, rien que pour soi...</h2>
            
            <br/>
            <p>Venez vous ressourcez dans un cadre chaleureux et reposant où les bienfaits des plantes et huiles essentielles viendront délicatement parfumer ce moment d'évasion...</p>
            <p>Aurélie Caucheteux, esthéticienne et pédicure médicale diplômée de l'école privée MOTTARD à Namur vous prodiguera dans la bonne humeur, la relaxation et le bien-être, des soins de qualité à la hauteur de vos envies et de vos espérances.</p>
            <p>L'accueil, l'ambiance et la qualité des services que vous propose aurélie sont sa priorité. Tout est étudié et conçu pour votre bien-être et satisfaction.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: @MattHolbrook-Bull LOL, I try, sometimes ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue with using width only (instead of max-width) is that the picture can get bigger than its original size which is not something I want (see this interesting article http://demosthenes.info/blog/586/CSS-Fluid-Image-Techniques-for-Responsive-Site-Design).

Comment: @Greg In that case, set `width: auto;` so that the `width` will be of the original size.

Comment: @Greg Even if you dont set any CSS to the image, the image rendered will be of the original width and height itself.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and I think the problem is that you specified in .presentation img that the max-width should be 100%. Instead you should try changing to simply width: 100%

Hope this help!